# Is laptop battery dying?

Tags: battery, dell-inspiron

Dell Inspiron 15 7567; Ubuntu 18.04.
Battery fully charged only for 49% of design value. Is laptop battery dying?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? What research have you done? Where have you got stuck? Please edit your question and include this information. [superuser.com/help/how-to-ask](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Batteries naturally wear out with time and with use. This is what you've observed.

Comment: it has lost 3 % for a month

Comment: That's not abnormal. This number doesn't get updated in real-time, it gets closer to real numbers when battery levels drop low.

Comment: OP: You can purchase aftermarket batteries for most regular style laptops. Newer laptops are not so simple. Most have in-built batteries - that's where things get tricky. It's a way for manufacturers to prevent you from using aftermarket. Ie.: you have to shell out the full price for a new OEM battery.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your battery is very much dying. Nominally batteries  which hold less them 80% of design capacity are considered in need of replacing, so yours is very much past its design life, and is dying.

I do note that that the stated battery capacity is pretty large for a modern laptop. If your laptop is not ancient I'm guessing this is some kind of extended runtime battery, and at 49% / 36wh left it likely performs similarly to a newish regular runtime battery (but without knowing the laptop model this is just speculation)

Comment: _"batteries which hold less them 80% of design capacity are considered in need of replacing"_ - citation neede

Comment: @gronostaj - See https://www.apple.com/batteries/service-and-recycling/, Post 7 at https://www.rcgroups.com/forums/showthread.php?2498322-How-to-know-if-a-lipo-battery-is-dead, Paragraph 2 at http://www.batteryeducation.com/2006/04/battery_degrada.html